# Return statement with keywords-and,or

Tags: python

```
def myfunc():    #f1
    return 0 or 1

#The above returns 1

def myfunc():    #f2
    return 1 or 0

#The above also returns 1

def myfunc():    #f3
    return 0 or -1

#The above returns -1

def myfunc():    #f4
    return -1 or 1

#The above returns -1

def myfunc():    #f5
    return 1 or -1
#The above returns 1

def myfunc():    #f6
    return 1 and -1
#The above returns 1
```

From `f1` , `f2` , `f3` returns the non zero value. But in case of `f4` and `f5` it returns the value immediately after the `return` keyword. But in case of `f6` , it returns -1 . I am not able to understand how this works.

*Thanks for the explanation :)*

Comment: I think it's short circuiting on the non-zero value as True hence the output you observe

Comment: `-1` and `1` are both "thuthy" values (`bool(-1) is True is bool(1)`). Boolean statement is short-circuited and does not check second argument.

Comment: Are you actually trying to return 2 values? In this case, try e.g. `return (1, -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` returns the first value if that is equivalent to True, otherwise it returns the second value.

In Python, any integer that is not 0 is True in a boolean context. So both 1 and -1 are True, and will be returned if the other value is 0.

`and` is the opposite: it returns the first value if it is *not* True, otherwise it returns the second value.

Comment: @MohitBhasi that is a very basic question, do you understand what `or` and `and` do?

Comment: @MohitBhasi, `and` returns the first False value or the last True value. `or` returns first True or last False.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(-1)
True
```

Keep in mind the truth table:

```
TRUE OR ANYTHING is TRUE
FALSE AND ANYTHING is FALSE
```

Comment: ok thx , i am going to edit my question pls check it out in 3mins

Answer (score 0):

This is called short-circuiting, that is how `and` `or` and `not` work.
You can see the docs about it here : https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

So in your function #f6, the first operand `1` evaluates to `True` but there is an `and` so python has to also evaluate the following `-1`.

If you take directly from the docs the definition of `x and y` applied to your case `1 and -1`, it says :

> if 1 is false, then 1, else -1

As `1` is not `False`, you get to the `else` part, and your `-1` is then returned.
That is why you get `-1` as return of the sixth function.